# Is the server down for MacPorts?

Tags: macos, macports, download

I've been trying for several hours ow to download MacPorts for OS X 10.10 Yosemite from https://www.macports.org/install.php

Unfortunately, I'm not able to access to the 'pkg' installers via the website.

For example, I've tried using the `wget`command on Terminal, i.e.

> wget "https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.3-10.10-Yosemite.pkg"

This is the response:

> `--2014-11-23 16:04:37--
>   Resolving distfiles.macports.org... 17.251.224.217
>   Connecting to distfiles.macports.org|17.251.224.217|:443... failed: Operation timed out.
>   Retrying.
>
> --2014-11-23 16:05:53--  (try: 2)
>   Connecting to distfiles.macports.org|17.251.224.217|:443... failed: Operation timed out.
>   Retrying.
>
> --2014-11-23 16:07:10--  (try: 3)
>   Connecting to distfiles.macports.org|17.251.224.217|:443...

And so on.

If the website is indeed down, is there another way to download MacPorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official servers have been down for the last few hours, you can however, also get the packages from [here](http://nue.de.distfiles.macports.org/macports/distfiles/MacPorts/).